# How to assign bean's property an Enum value in Spring config file?

Tags: java, spring

I have a standalone enum type defined, something like this:

```
package my.pkg.types;

public enum MyEnumType {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
}
```

Now, I want to inject a value of that type into a bean property:

```xml
<bean name="someName" class="my.pkg.classes">
   <property name="type" value="my.pkg.types.MyEnumType.TYPE1" />
</bean>
```

...and that didn't work :(

How should I Inject an Enum into a spring bean?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Have you tried just "TYPE1"? I suppose Spring uses reflection to determine the type of "type" anyway, so the fully qualified name is redundant. Spring generally doesn't subscribe to redundancy!

Comment: Pretty strange that the fully qualified name doesn't work.

Comment: But what if I want to use something like "${tes.db.database:ORACLE}" , i.e defaulting a property. It fails to work. Please help

Answer (score 46):

Use the value child element instead of the value attribute and specify the Enum class name:

```xml
<property name="residence">
    <value type="SocialSecurity$Residence">ALIEN</value>
</property>
```

The advantage of this approach over just writing `value="ALIEN"` is that it also works if Spring can't infer the actual type of the enum from the property (e.g. the property's declared type is an interface).<sub>*Adapted from  araqnid's comment.*</sub>

Comment: This works if Spring can't infer the actual type of the enum from the property (e.g. the property is just an interface)

Comment: @araqnid: Good point. I took the liberty of adding it to the answer.

Comment: @Tsering : Can I use Spring EL within value tag? ${abc:ALIEN}

Answer (score 35):

I know this is a really old question, but in case someone is looking for the newer way to do this, use the spring util namespace:

```
<util:constant static-field="my.pkg.types.MyEnumType.TYPE1" />
```

As described in the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html).

Answer (score 12):

You can just do "TYPE1".

Answer (score 6):

This is what did it for me MessageDeliveryMode is the enum the bean will have the value PERSISTENT:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageDeliveryMode" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="PERSISTENT" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using SPEL and P-NAMESPACE:

```
<beans...
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" ...>
..
<bean name="someName" class="my.pkg.classes"
    p:type="#{T(my.pkg.types.MyEnumType).TYPE1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be specific, set the value to be the name of a constant of the enum type, e.g., "TYPE1" or "TYPE2" in your case, as shown below. And it will work:

```xml
<bean name="someName" class="my.pkg.classes">
   <property name="type" value="TYPE1" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write Bean Editors (details are in the Spring Docs) if you want to add further value and write to custom types.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-integration example, routing based on a an Enum field:

```
public class BookOrder {

    public enum OrderType { DELIVERY, PICKUP } //enum
    public BookOrder(..., OrderType orderType) //orderType
    ...
```

config:

```
<router expression="payload.orderType" input-channel="processOrder">
    <mapping value="DELIVERY" channel="delivery"/>
    <mapping value="PICKUP" channel="pickup"/>
</router>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enum:

```
package my.pkg.types;

public enum MyEnumType {
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2
}
```

You may instantiate it as a bean within this xml config

```
<bean name="someName" class="my.pkg.types.MyEnumType" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="TYPE1"/>
</bean>
```