# How to set int property with enum in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a property of int and I have an enum. How can I set the int property using the enum in Spring bean configuration?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private int type1;

    public void setType1(int type1) {
        this.type1 = type1;
    }
}

public enum MyEnumType1 {
    TYPE1(1),
    TYPE2(2);

    private final int index;

    private MyEnumType1(int i) {
        this.index = i;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

I tried the following but did not work.

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.example.HelloWorld">
    <property name="type1" value="TYPE1.index" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `MyEnumType1.TYPE1.index` along with package? There is no way to guess where `TYPE1` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.example.HelloWorld">
    <property name="type1" value="#{T(com.MyEnum).TYPE1.index}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: some explanatory text would help this answer

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
public void setType1(MyEnumType1 type1) {
this.type1 = type1.getIndex();
}

<bean id="helloBean" class="com.example.HelloWorld">
  <property name="type1" value="TYPE1 />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring application context:

```
<util:map id="myMap">
  <entry key="#{T(com.MyEnum).ELEM1}" value="value1" />
  <entry key="#{T(com.MyEnum).ELEM2}" value="value2" />
</util:map>
```

Class where the `Map` gets injected:

```
public class MyClass {

    private @Resource Map<MyEnum, String> myMap;
}
```

The important things to note are that in the Spring context I used SpEL (Spring Expression Language) which is only available since version 3.0. `@Resource` auto-injects the values by bean name.

The answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174308/spring-how-do-you-set-enum-keys-in-a-map-with-annotations) page can help you. Have a look at it.