# Spring enums in a map

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have two enumerateds:

```
public enum One implements Representable{
   ONE
}
public enum Two implements Representable{
   TWO
}
```

Now, I need to declare the following spring-bean:

```
<bean id="listGeneratorContainer" class="pack.age.Container>
    <property name="generators">
        <map key-type="pack.age.Representable"> <!-- How to specuify the Type? -->
            <entry key="ONE" value="1"/>
            <entry key="TWO" value="2"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

where

```
package pack.age;

public class Container{
    private Map<Representable, Interger> generators
    //GET, SET, staff
}
```

Is it possible to tell spring to inject enums of the different types? In the case of a single enum that's clear.

It's not working now:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [pack.age.Representable]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:362)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the way to embed Enum as keys in spring map definition.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174308/spring-how-do-you-set-enum-keys-in-a-map-with-annotations) is an example post for the same.

```
<util:map id="myMap">
  <entry key="#{T(com.acme.MyEnum).ELEM1}" value="value1" />
  <entry key="#{T(com.acme.MyEnum).ELEM2}" value="value2" />
</util:map>
```

Make sure you reference it like above.
So in your case it would be something like this.

```
<bean id="listGeneratorContainer" class="pack.age.Container>
<property name="generators">
    <map key-type="pack.age.Representable"> 
        <entry key="#{T(pack.age.ONE)ONE}" value="1"/>
        <entry key="#{T(pack.age.TWO)TWO}" value="2"/>
    </map>
</property>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I personally think if both enums are using same interface, merge them into one. Like ONE, TWO.

Comment: BTW, I've already found a way to do that, before you post your answer. I used custom PropertyEditor. But, thank you anyway