# enum to class object conversion

Tags: java, spring, enums

I get enum value as input, each enum value corresponds to a class.
How do I define spring configuration given enum value should convert to class object

```
public enum R {
eR1,
eR2,
eR3;
}

//simple interface
interface R {
    dosomething();
}

//R1 class
class R1 implements R {
    dosomething() {
    //implmentation for R1
    }
}

//R2 class
class R2 implements R {
    dosomething() {
        //implementation for R2
    }
}
```

I have API say,

```
getR(R er1) {
   //How do I define spring configuration to get class object given enum value??
}

I want to avoid if conditions in API, something like this
getR(R er) {
    if(er.equals(R.eR1)) {
        //do this
    } else if(er.equals(R.eR2)) {
       //do this
    }
}
I want to spring to inject right class based on input parameter so that I can avoid if statement.
```

say for three enum fields I want to avoid having three id's in spring.

```
Can I define somethign like this
<bean id="r" class="com.myProject.R1">
    <property name="er1" value="eR1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="r" class="com.myProject.R2">
    <property name="er2" value="eR2"/>
</bean>
//similary for R3 as well
```

Answer (score 1):

In your spring configuration just use the enum value

sample if you want to inject eR2 inside R2 ,

```
 <bean id="r2" class="com.myProject.R2">
     <property name="er2" value="eR2"/>
 </bean>
```

see a sample [here](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/05/creating-spring-bean-from-java-5-enum.html) . You need not use the fully qualified name . See a discussion at [How assign bean's property an Enum value in Spring config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516771/how-assign-beans-property-an-enum-value-in-spring-config-file) .

Comment: I have updated question please check, how do I avoid unnecessary if statements

Comment: Any one have suggestion on this?