# How to use java enum as bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

My goal I want to achieve is to inject enum to Spring managed bean.

I do not want my bean be configured in XML (there no reason to do so except this not-working enum).

I have simple maven project:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.spring.enum-injection</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I created simple test

```java
import net.betlista.spring.enum_injection.EnumInjectionComponent;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    EnumInjectionComponent component;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(component.roundingMode);
    }

}
```

and my bean is

```java
package net.betlista.spring.enum_injection;

import java.math.RoundingMode;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EnumInjectionComponent {

    @Autowired
    public RoundingMode roundingMode;

}
```

When I'm trying to run my test Ipm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enumInjectionComponent': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.math.RoundingMode net.betlista.spring.enum_injection.EnumInjectionComponent.roundingMode; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.math.RoundingMode] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public java.math.RoundingMode net.betlista.spring.enum_injection.EnumInjectionComponent.roundingMode; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.math.RoundingMode] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.math.RoundingMode] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:948)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 41 more
```

But in log I can see:

> INFO: Destroying singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@236527f:
>   defining beans
>   [org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,enumInjectionComponent,rounding,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor];
>   root of factory hierarchy

So I have rounding bean in context.

What I missed?

edit: I just found, the problem is with Spring version 3.1.x only, in 3.2.x it works, any workaround available?

edit2: here is definition of beans

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.betlista"/>

    <bean id="rounding" class="java.math.RoundingMode" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="UP" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

edit3:

as workaround I used Dev Blanked's workaround to specify the list, and use @Value in my bean as

```
@Value("#{roundingModes[0]}")
public RoundingMode roundingMode;
```

if there is a better (nicer) solution I'd like to see it ;-)

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Are you trying to inject a `RoundingMode` enum value you have defined somewhere? Trying to inject the Enum itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: No need to `pom.xml` file here, paste the bean xml file instead.

Comment: context config added

@PeterMularien why it doesn't make sense? I want to have rounding configurable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516771/how-assign-beans-property-an-enum-value-in-spring-config-file)

Comment: @Betlista: The question is clearer now that you posted the Spring configuration - thanks! Have you tried moving the `<bean>` declaration for the enum up in the context configuration, before the `<context:component-scan>`?

Comment: @codelark gave you a reference to the right answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/11443028/655756

Comment: I saw that question before I tried it and according to log above, `rounding` bean is correctly in context, AFAIK there is no problem with rounding bean initialization, just with injection to component...

Comment: @Charles why did you remove spring-3.1 tag when there is written in question that it works fine in 3.2, but it's not working in 3.1 ?

Comment: @Betlista, as noted in the edit description, the existing [tag:spring-3] tag very expressly covers *all* 3.x versions of Spring.  We don't need a new version-specific tag here.

Comment: @Charles Hm :-/ Probably I'm missing something, because as spring-3 covers ALL 3.x version and this problem is NOT in 3.2.x version, this tagging is not correct. On the other hand Spring 3.1 is Spring-3 that's why I used this tag too, for example when someone has Spring-3 in favorite tags...

Comment: Moving `<bean>` before `<context:component-scan>` solved my problem. Thanks @PeterMularien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to provide the bare enum name and specify the value-type. below is an example where the rounding mode has been injected to a list. should be the same for a property as well.

```xml
<util:list id="roundingModes" value-type="java.math.RoundingMode">
    <value>UP</value>
</util:list>
```

Comment: As far as there is not better solution now I'm accepting this woraround (description how I used it is added in question - edit3)

Comment: value-type can be specified for a property in a bean as well. So if there is a bean having a property called 'roundingMode' it should be possible to inject the value directly by using the value-type

Comment: I think I do not understand, because my bean is not in XML configuration - component scan is used...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach one can use is to specify UP as String and in bean implement [InitializingBean interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and create the enum in `afterPropertiesSet()` from that String.

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    roundingMode = RoundingMode.valueOf(roundingModeName);
}
```