# Java 8/Spring constants in PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot project I have defined a following RestController method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('" + Permission.APPEND_DECISION + "')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/decisions", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public DecisionResponse appendDecisionToParent(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId, @Valid @RequestBody AppendDecisionRequest decisionRequest) {
    ....
    return new DecisionResponse(decision);
}
```

Right now in order to provide allowed authority name I use a following code construction:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('" + Permission.APPEND_DECISION + "')")
```

where `Permission.APPEND_DECISION` is a constant:

```
public static final String APPEND_DECISION = "APPEND_DECISION";
```

Is there any more elegant way in Java/Spring in order to define such kind of code ?

Comment: You can create a special shortly-named permissions-aware bean (say, just `P`) with getters that expose the constants. So you could write down something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(@P.appendDecision)")`. This is far away from being perfect, though. Or perhaps you might also experiment with `StandardEvaluationContext#lookupVariable(String)` to bind a variable to a specific name -- it looks like a way to go. Customizing the evaluation context is a sort of fun, and I recently configured it for custom types support in the context of Spring Security.

Comment: Maybe with [String.concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) `"hasAuthority('".concat(APPEND_DECISION).concat("')")`

Comment: @oliv37 Java annotations may/can only accept compile-time constants.

Comment: did you try with this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444856/using-static-variables-in-spring-annotations) using spring expression language : `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(T(fully.qualified.OtherClass).ROLE)");`

Comment: Another way to go probably is obtaining the `StandardEvaluationContext` bean and invoke its `setVariable(String,Object)` method.

Comment: Thank you all! I have reimplemented this logic in a way suggested by oli37

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [oli37](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521607/oliv37) I have implemented this logic in a following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return defaultMethodExpressionHandler;
    }

    public class DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

        @Override
        public StandardEvaluationContext createEvaluationContextInternal(final Authentication auth, final MethodInvocation mi) {
            StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext = super.createEvaluationContextInternal(auth, mi);
            ((StandardTypeLocator) standardEvaluationContext.getTypeLocator()).registerImport(Permission.class.getPackage().getName());
            return standardEvaluationContext;
        }
    }

}


    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(T(Permission).APPEND_DECISION)")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/decisions", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public DecisionResponse appendDecisionToParent(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId, @Valid @RequestBody AppendDecisionRequest decisionRequest) {
    ...
        return new DecisionResponse(decision);
    }
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is a simple approach to defining authorities in a single place that doesn't require any in-depth Spring Security config.

```
public class Authority {
    public class Plan{
        public static final String MANAGE = "hasAuthority('PLAN_MANAGE')";
        public static final String APPROVE = "hasAuthority('PLAN_APPROVE')";
        public static final String VIEW = "hasAuthority('PLAN_VIEW')";
    }
}
```

Securing services...

```
public interface PlanApprovalService {

    @PreAuthorize(Authority.Plan.APPROVE)
        ApprovalInfo approvePlan(Long planId);

    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant Solution

Answer (score 1):

I thing the good way is not to mixed both

You can have constants

```
public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "auth_app_admin";
```

and have that other side

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + Constants.ROLE_ADMIN + "\")")
```

this is much clear