# How to set bean name by enumeration value in spring

Tags: java, spring, enums

I want to set name of bean by values of an enum. for example :

I defined this bean in my XMLconfig:

```
<bean name="something" class="example.Sample"/>
```

I have an enum with these value:

```
BEAN_NAME_ONE("one"),
BEAN_NAME_TWO("two");
```

I want to set the name of my bean by above values. How i can do that ?

Comment: You mean you want to use the name of "one" or "BEAN_NAME_ONE" ?

Comment: have you refferd this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516771/how-assign-beans-property-an-enum-value-in-spring-config-file). Suppose it has the solution for you.

Comment: @Adam the "one".

Comment: @RajithPemabandu No,that works in value.